# Sometime Crash while Image compress in different android device

Tags: android, image, android-camera-intent, image-compression

This is my compress code:

```
                Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(temp, 100, 50);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

My problem is it work good for few device.
But few device it's crash.

Why ??

Comment: Post the stacktrace for the crashes. And try to recycle the bitmap after compression.

Comment: Most probably an out of memory exception,

Answer (score 0):

For OS version above 19 it may crash.
Try below solution.

```
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                {
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
                    try {
                        parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedImage, "r");
                        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It crashed when compress image

Comment: Yes because bmp might be null here. Use above code and debug to check whether you are getting any value in bmp.

Comment: @RashiduzzamanKhan I am not asking it to increase my score but it will indicate others that the asnwer is useful. If you don't want to do that then it is fine.